# How to make the request body optional

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I've got the following POST function:

```
public async Task<BaseResponse> Post([FromBody] BodyParams content)
{
    var option = content.TopOnly;
    return await RunHttpMethodAsync(option, _worker.Lookup);
}
```

Here's the BodyParams class:

```
public class BodyParams
{
    public bool TopOnly { get; set; }
}
```

This works as intended. However, I'd like to make `BodyParams content` as optional, and set `TopOnly` to `true` if not provided. I've tried:

```
public class BodyParams
{
    public bool TopOnly { get; set; } = true;
}
```

And then not providing a body, but I get the following return:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "status": 415,
    "traceId": "00-305034a9723b9a4f94e0601c6ecc3587-b67fe89deb8e644f-00"
}
```

I put a breakpoint on my `var option`, and I don't even reach that.

My question is, how can I make the request body optional for POSTs?

Comment: Show us how do you make a POST. You need to specify Content-Type = "application/json"

Comment: @RomanMarusyk: I'm using PostMan to test my API route. When I add `Content-Type = "application/json"` to the headers in PostMan, I get an error: `A non-empty request body is required.`. Which is the opposite of what I'd like to achieve.

Comment: Please show us the postman screen

Comment: (Untested...) have you tried `[FromBody] BodyParams content = null`

Comment: Can't you make an overload that does not have the body param?

Answer (score 1):

*415 Unsupported Media Type* - means that the request entity has a media type which the server or resource does not support.

If you use Postman, set this and try again
[image]

Also, to make it simpler, you can use

```
public async Task<BaseResponse> Post([FromBody] TopOnly? topOnly = true)
```